# Blazor server - Azure AD auth - fine in dev, deployed to Azure App not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side

I'm struggling with Azure AD authentication on my Blazor Server app, but only when deployed to an Azure App service.

My app is presenting the login screen, and appears to authenticate me.

Every page appears to result in just a single line

"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

After login, I get that line.

I attempt to go to /counter, same line....

I do not get this after login when running from my IIS Express dev machine, after authentication, I get the index page, can nav to counter, fetch data, etc.

I take it there is something different between development environment and production.

1. I tried to deploy my debug configuration, same result.
2. I don't see where this "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." message is coming from, at all.. I don't see it on any components or pages.
3. I'm using the V2 end points for MSAL, and again, they seem to work okay in development
4. Do I need to add an attribute to my page or component? Do I need to set up a specific role somewhere in Azure App?
5. What should I have in startup.cs or program.cs?

Again, I've put my actual app aside and just spun up a new one with just the default counter and fetch data demo stuff, used VS to add Microsoft Identity, run thru the config steps for it, all successfully. Run from dev machine, it asks me to log in, I log in, it shows I'm logged in on the login control, etc. All looks fine. Hit deploy and spin up an App Service for it, deploys without error, starts up, asks me to login, I do, and I get the You do not have permission line

Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging using  user ID under Azure Active Directory (AAD), you have to modify in Settings:

- Authentication / Authorization
- App Service Authentication, "ON" =>> choose: Log in With Azure Active Directory
- Select 'ActivityProvider',  AAD.
- Configured (Express: Existing APP)
- Manage Azure Active Directory: Manage Permission & Manage Application
  For Manage Permission ==>> Add, In Delegate Permission, choose: Sign in and read user profile and refresh your browser to login again.

[image]
Also,  check all your web app files though `KUDU Console`.

Follow this link,

`<your_web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net` > `Debug Console` (from top menu) > `CMD/PowerShell` > `Site` > `wwwroot`.

That should contains all your files.